# Does stringstream initializing with big length buffer doubles memory usage

Tags: c++, buffer, sstream

Suppose I have a buffer with length 100MB `char[100*1024*1024]`. I would like to use stringstream facilities on this buffer like format read so I defined a new `stringstream ss(arr)` using this array. So I would like to learn if my program uses 200MB in total at runtime or not? I am working on big data and memory usage is critical. Actually I defined a char buffer and initialize my custom istream with this buffer and solved my memory issue. But I am still in confusion whether my second way is redundant or not.

Comment: Why don't you simply *measure* it yourself?

Comment: I tried by changing original buffer and as it is expected it did not effect stringstream. Using other tools like valgrind, xcode I could not get it they show no info about internal mechanism of stringstream. Since it is a critical issue I just would like to be sure when stringstream is initialized with and array is there a memory allocation as size of buffer.

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to have duplication. I don't read any any certainty from the standard, but `stringstream` contains a `stringbuf`, and `stringbuf` usually requires a resizable character sequence. Your array isn't resizable. What will probably happen is your 100 MB buffer will be converted to a `std::string` and the `string` will form the basis of the `stringbuf`.

Comment: Have a look at boost::iostream's [array device](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/array.html). It allows you to treat an array as a stream without doing any new allocations. The array device doesn't own the array in contrast to `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I would like to learn if my program uses 200MB in total at runtime
>   or not?

If you construct a `stringstream` from a char array it will *at least* double the memory usage. From the reference of [`std::basic_stringstream` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream):

> Uses a copy of str as initial contents of the underlying string
>   device.

You could write your own stream buffer to create a non-owning stringstream, but the [boost::iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) library already provides that via [array devices](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/array.html).

```
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

char str[100*1024*1024];

// No copy of str is made here! The stream just stores pointer and size of array.
io::stream<io::array_source> strm( str, sizeof(str) );

// Do something with the stream as usual. It is fully compatible with standard streams.
int x;
strm >> x;
```

There is a nice **online compiler** that shows peak memory usage.
In the following examples I'm creating a stream from a 10 MiB array.

[Live example using `std::stringstream`](http://rextester.com/YLVMS4234). Peaks at 31(!) MiB.

[Live example using `boost::array_source`](http://rextester.com/CKFQ68127). Peaks at only 11 MiB.

Why there is a peak memory usage of even **3x** the char array size when using `std::stringstream`? Because we must create a temporary `string` from the char array first as `std::stringstream` doesn't have a constructor that takes a char pointer.